# Random Forest Classifier testing the accuracy of the model in Python

Tags: python, model, random-forest

I can't succeed to evaluate the performance of my model which is a random forest classifier. Please can someone help me to find the right code.

```
depth1 = np.arange(1, 30)
estimators1 = np.arange(1, 100)
score = []
for depth in depth1:
for estimators in estimators1:
    forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=estimators, max_depth=depth)
    forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
    score.append(forest.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Best depth for {} estimators:{}.".format(estimators1[np.argmax(score)], depth1[np.argmax(score)]))</i>
```

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the `max_depth` and `n_estimators` hyperparameters?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what exactly you are trying to do and how the result of the code you posted differs from what you expect it to do?

Comment: I am trying to optimize the max_depth and n_estimators in order to obtain the best score. The problem is that the accuracy is equal to 1 and it doesn't seem to be correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: It's hard to say without much more information but it looks like you are training and scoring on the same data. If your accuracy is coming out at 1, then you are probably overfitting. Try adding `forest.predict(X_test)` and score based on that. Depending on your data size, I would also increase `min_samples_split` from the default of 2. Also, look into using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) instead of writing your own function.